# Get link from iframe src

Tags: iframe

I am trying to get a link from an iframe, when it changes. I have iframe of one site, on different domain. I am trying to get a second link, when iframe redirected to a different page.
For example, default iframe on site hosts a form. After form is completed, it redirects to another page and then src in iframe changes. I am not able to get a link from iframe, not even sure if that is possible. 
I was googling, but whatever I tried doesnt work for me.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
            }

            #content
            {
                position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <iframe id="iframe" samesite=None width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" 
            src="www.site.com/" />

        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                 console.log('asdsadsa');
             var link = document.getElementById("iframe").src;

             console.log(link);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Not sure if this is possible, any advice is appreciated.